# Field is updating with NULL value even though it is excluded from Propery Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a Model as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And my Controller has Actions to Edit the Model as follows:

```
    public ActionResult MyProfile(int id)
    {
        var currentUser = _context.ApplicationUsers.Find(applicationuser.Id);
        return View(currentUser);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyProfile([Bind(Exclude="Password")]ApplicationUser applicationuser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Entry(applicationuser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(applicationuser);
    }
```

Here, POST method is updating the **FullName** and **Email** fields properly. But, It's updating NULL value to **Password** field. How to avoid this?

Comment: Aren't you telling it to exclude Password in the binding (Sorry, haven't done a lot of work with the built in model binder). Wouldn't you expect it to be null?

Comment: I don't want to update the "Password" field, i want the initial value to be present always.

Comment: The default value for a string is Null. You are telling the model binder to ignore the Password property, and thus it will never be set to anything.

Comment: No, assume that I have already created a object of this class with some values assigned. No I'm updating the values of the same object

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.  Since you are binding directly to your entity framework object, the default value for any property not in the bind property list will be it's default value for the type.  in this case NULL.  to do this properly, create a separate view model and map it to the appropriate ef model fields.

Comment: Your editing data so ALWAYS use a view model (and then get your data model in the post method and map its properties from the view model) - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). And a view model to editing a users profile will never include a password field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here bind attribute'll not help you out put this line before `savechanges()`

`db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false`

Comment: This is Amazing! I have added this and working as expected. Now Password field is not updating and I'm seeing the original values.